# Right to left support Components for .Net

Tags: .net, components, right-to-left

i am searching in internet to find Right to left support component packages. as You know there are many packages there (like devexpress, Component one, Netadvantage, .... ) 
i dont know any of them, would you please tell me which one of them is rtl support ? 
because i want to use them in a Persian (Farsi Language) project.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Any decent UI control library will implement globalization support, the ones you listed should all have it.  Best to email the vendor directly.